# Getting NetworkInterface name from NetworkInfo

Tags: android, networking

Given an instance of android.net.NetworkInfo I want to open a socket for corresponding type. For that purpose I "just" neet to convert NetworkInfo type (such as ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) to java.net.NetworkInterface type (e.g. "wlan0").

I prefer to do it without if-s and switch-s, as some previous posts report that this is not guaranteed to work (e.g. a Wifi interface may come out as "wlan0" or as "eth0").

Is there a safe way to go?

Comment: Found something on that?